# SQL comand for adding a row in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simple question but a search online yields no results.  In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, what is the Query for adding a new row?  I want to know what the actual script is.  If one of the fields is auto-incremented, how is that managed in the sql command?

Comment: Look up `INSERT` Statment and `Identity`

Comment: It would be a very good idea (based on this question alone) for you to Google "SQL Tutorials" and work your way through one. :-)

Comment: *... a search online yields no results.*  Actually, there are numerous results: https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+query+to+add+new+row&oq=SQL+Server+query+to+add+new+row&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60l2j0.13837j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have two columns autoNum and MyColumNName in table called tablename...

```
Insert into tableName (MyColumnName) Values ('Test');
```

you don't need to include the autonumber field as the system will automatically handle it.

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e083/2/2